# DrawingBrush to WPF DataGrid cells as Background

Tags: wpf, datagrid, drawingbrush

I'd like to set a `DrawingBrush` to `DataGridCell`and I use

```
<DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" ViewportUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox" Viewport="0,0,0.05,1">
     <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
         <DrawingGroup>
              <GeometryDrawing>
                   <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                         <Pen Brush="Gray" Thickness="0.05"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                          <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,0" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
              </GeometryDrawing>
          </DrawingGroup>
     </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

I have undesired result when `DataGridCells` have unequal widths like below.

[image]

How should I change the Brush so that regardles of the widht of the individual cells the result would look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change `ViewportUnits` from `RelativeToBoundingBox` to `Absolute` and adjust `Viewport`.

> The coordinate system is not relative to a bounding box. Values are interpreted directly in local space.

Something like this:

```
<DrawingBrush 
    x:Key="DrawingBrush" 
    TileMode="Tile" 
    ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
    Viewport="0,0,5,15">
```

which looks like this

[image: result]